# add mulitple uitextfields on button press

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button which dynamically adds a UITextField to a view in xcode. I want to keep pressing the button to add as many textfields to the view underneath one another, but I do not know how to do this

here is my code so far:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {


    let sampleTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(20, 100, 300, 40))
    sampleTextField.placeholder = "Enter text here"
    sampleTextField.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
    sampleTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
    sampleTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
    sampleTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
    sampleTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
    sampleTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing;
    sampleTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center
    sampleTextField.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(sampleTextField)
    print(sampleTextField.text!)

}
```

im aware this adds one texfield and by pressing the button a new textfield overlaps
i would like to press the button and to add another

Comment: Why not use a UITableView with the UITextField  and the addButton as the last cell ? (more easy to manage and implement)

Comment: I'm new to swift so not aware of how to do this

Comment: Check this step by step tutorial, it may help you.https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/02/12/custom-uitableviewcell-text-input-swift/

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the next textfield underneath, you need to modify the y frame in your function.

Create a variable to hold the y origin value and add its value at the end of your function.

```
var yValue = 100

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let sampleTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(20, yValue, 300, 40))
    sampleTextField.placeholder = "Enter text here"
    sampleTextField.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
    sampleTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
    sampleTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
    sampleTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
    sampleTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
    sampleTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing;
    sampleTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center
    sampleTextField.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(sampleTextField)
    print(sampleTextField.text!)

    yValue += 50
}
```